# How to load default visible content for click on display script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

Can someone please help me to load a default content into a certain div that displays hidden content when a certain link is clicked? And also I would like the fadeIn and fadeOut transition to be smoother - currently it fadeIns before it fadeOuts then FadeIn again.

This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//loads default content
$('.reserved-area').load($('.menu_top a:first-child').attr('href'));

$('.o-links').click(function() {

  // href has to be the id of the hidden content element
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.reserved-area')
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .html($(href).html())
      .fadeIn(1000);

  return false;
});

});
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="menu_top">
  <a href="#reserved-area" class="o-links">Content1</a> |
  <a href="#reserved-area2" class="o-links">Content2</a> |
  <a href="#reserved-area3" class="o-links">Content3</a>
</div>

<div class="reserved-area">
</div>

<div id="reserved-area">
  <img src="test-img-1.jpg" class="reserved-img">
</div>

<div id="reserved-area2">
  <img src="test-img-1.jpg" class="reserved-img">
</div>

<div id="reserved-area3">
  <img src="test-img-2.jpg" class="reserved-img">
</div>
```

Comment: Other than the solution that has been provided for the fadeIn/fadeOut issue by just using a callback function, what is the other issue exactly?  The code looks fine, given that each link has the class of ".o-links".  Is that the case?

Comment: Josh the other issue is that I want ".reserved-area" div to load some default content. Currently nothing shows unless I click on a click. Can you please help me with this. I don't know why the above code isn't working. It seems to make sense.

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML, and perhaps a jsfiddle?

Comment: okay, I'll provide the html. Please wait... the html is there now. Hope that helps.

Comment: Any idea the issue is? in the script whenever I add this line: `$('.reserved-area').load($('.menu_top a:first-child').attr('href'));` the whole thing malfunctions.

Comment: when do you want to load the default content inside the `div` ?

Comment: watou, I want it to be loaded immediately (as soon as the page loads).

Comment: Why not write directly in the html code ?

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fadein the content of the `div` tag after the end of fadeOut operation by doing this :

```
  ......
  $('.reserved-area')
  .fadeOut(1000, function () {
       $(this).html($(href).html()).fadeIn(1000);
  });
  .....
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you help me with the other issue please. I want to load some default content into the div I specified in the description.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7Nd8/1/) a solution (may be it's not best way to that).

- The default content is written directly inside the HTML code.
- I replace images by some texts.
- I replace `href` attribute value (I remove the `#`), and I added it on JS code.

Hope it's helps.

Comment: I've been playing around with this but for some reason it won't work like the jsfiddle. Thanks so much helping me out, but it's just not working right.

Comment: Thanks it's working now. I forgot to take the the div that the contents are loaded into off hidden in the css. Thanks a million.

Comment: Hey is there way to select two answers to my question? So sorry I can only select one answer. That sucks

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me the books you read when you were learning jquery and javascript? Please!

Comment: Really?! I would have imagined you read a book or something. Okay thanks again. Will give that a try, though I'm a bit of special case, hope that learning method works for me. LOL!